# How to automatically discover dependencies of a .Net Standard project?

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have created a .Net Standard 2.0 project that handles HTTP calls for my users. It automatically manages formatting API HTTP calls as well as handling token timeouts, etc. I want my users to be able to utilize this DLL within their own .Net projects.

It would be nice if there was some way in .Net to let them auto-discover the nuget dependencies of my project. I noticed that compiling my project creates a deps.json file which has a list of the dependencies in it. Can my users consume this somehow or do they have to manually set the dependencies in their own Visual Studio projects?